# Handling bad schema rows spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Problem 1:

Defined schema:

```
from pyspark.sql import types as t
ext_meas_schema = t.StructType(
    [
        t.StructField("value", t.DoubleType(), False),
        t.StructField("id", t.StringType(), False),
        t.StructField("timeGenerated", t.TimestampType(), False),
        t.StructField("startTimestamp", t.TimestampType(), False),
        t.StructField("endTimestamp", t.TimestampType(), False),
        t.StructField("quality", t.StringType(), False),
        t.StructField("type", t.StringType(), False),
        t.StructField("_corrupt_record", t.StringType(), True)
    ]
)
```

Simple code to read using readstream:

```
df=(spark.readStream
         .format("json")
         .schema(ext_meas_schema)
         .option("header", "false")
         .option("multiLine", "true")
         .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
         .json("abfss://sandbox@datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/test_datatype"))
```

json file being read, containing records

```
[
    {
        "value": 67.2758629803405,
        "id": "XYZ",
        "timeGenerated": "2024-01-24T14:31:24.5621139Z",
        "startTimestamp": "2024-01-23T13:30:03",
        "endTimestamp": "2024-01-23T14:30:03",
        "quality": "Good",
        "type": "Analog"
    },
    {
        "value": 0.0,
        "id": "ABC",
        "timeGenerated": "2024-01-24T14:31:24.5621319Z",
        "startTimestamp": "2024-01-23T13:30:03",
        "endTimestamp": "2024-01-23T14:30:03",
        "quality": "Good",
        "type": "Analog"
    },
    {
        "value": null,
        "id": "DEF",
        "timeGenerated": "2024-01-24T14:31:24.5987443Z",
        "startTimestamp": "2024-01-24T12:30:03",
        "endTimestamp": "2024-01-24T13:30:03",
        "quality": "Good",
        "type": "Analog"
    }
]
```

leads to all rows making through , and the last record not captured in the `_corrupt_record` column (`value` field is defined as not nullable in the schema and it is `null`, as you can see in the last record).

Problem 2:

Same code and schema, but now the input json file contains

```
[
    {
        "value": 67.2758629803405,
        "id": "ABC",
        "timeGenerated": "2024-01-24T14:31:24.5621139Z",
        "startTimestamp": "2024-01-23T13:30:03",
        "endTimestamp": "2024-01-23T14:30:03",
        "quality": "Good",
        "type": "Analog"
    },
    {
        "value": 0.0,
        "id": "XYZ",
        "timeGenerated": "2024-01-24T14:31:24.5621319Z",
        "startTimestamp": "2024-01-23T13:30:03",
        "endTimestamp": "2024-01-23T14:30:03",
        "quality": "Good",
        "type": "Analog"
    },
    {
        "value": "",
        "id": "DEF",
        "timeGenerated": "2024-01-24T14:31:24.5987443Z",
        "startTimestamp": "2024-01-24T12:30:03",
        "endTimestamp": "2024-01-24T13:30:03",
        "quality": "Good",
        "type": "Analog"
    }
]
```

In this case, all the rows get captured in the `_corrupt_record` column and not just the last row. Also, they get treated as a single bad row. I would have expected 2 rows to go in, and the last to show in the `_corrupt_record` column.

I can't seem to upload screenshots from the tests, to make it visually more clear .

How do I let Spark, only move the last row (in each of the 2 problem statements) to the `_corrupt_record` column, and treat the rest of the rows as good data?

I have gone through various stackoverflow posts, but none seem to work - I saw one with mode being set (and you would see I set the `mode` to `PERMISSIVE` along with defining a `_corrupt_record` column in my schema)